Centralisers of elements in a Lie algebra
I am considering the centraliser subgroup of some specific elements in a Lie algebra.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over characteristic $0$. Let us consider some elements $x:=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots , x_n\} \subset \mathfrak{g}$. Then using root space decomposition, i.e., $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{t}\oplus \underset{\alpha \in \Phi}{\oplus} \langle u_\alpha \rangle$, we can define the following two subsets:
$S_x^+:=\{\alpha\in \Phi^+\,|\, c_\alpha\neq 0,\ c_\alpha u_\alpha \in x_i\ \text{for some }i\}$
and
$S_x^-:=\{\beta\in \Phi^-\,|\, c_\beta \neq 0, \ c_\beta u_\beta \in x_j\ \text{for some }j\}.$
Let $sr(G)$ be the semisimple rank of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Then my assumption is that $S_x^+$ and $S_x^-$ are not contained in any $R^+$  and $R^-$,  where $R^+$ (resp. $R^-$) is generated by at most $sr(G)-1$ independent roots in $\Phi^+$ (resp. $\Phi^-$). Then I think that this is equivalent to $\langle x_1, \ldots , x_n\rangle$ is not contained in any proper parabolic subalgebra containing $\mathfrak{t}$.
In this case, my guess is the following:
Guess. The centraliser subset of $x$ is $C_{\mathfrak{g}}(x)=\{ g\in \mathfrak{g}\,|\, [g,x_i]=0\ \text{for  all }i\}=\underset{\alpha\in S_x^+\cup S_x^-}{\cap} \operatorname{ker}(\alpha)$.
Even if this is not true, it would be helpful to show that $\operatorname{dim}(C_\mathfrak{g}(x))=\operatorname{dim}(Z(\mathfrak{g}))$.
I am considering arbitrary Lie algebras, but at least $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ would be helpful to me. I appreciate any of your comments in advance.

So $\mathfrak g$ is reductive, not just an abstract Lie algebra. Then your notation says the $x_i$s are elements and the $u_\alpha$s are subspaces. So what does $c_\alpha u_\alpha \in x_i$ mean? Finally, when you say "although this is not true", do you mean that you know that it is not true (in which case, what is a counterexample?) or that you don't know whether it is true, and would accept the equality of dimensions instead if it is false? (I don't know if it's true because I don't understand the statement yet.)

Yes, so $\mathfrak{g}$ is reductive. In my notation, $c_\alpha u_\alpha \in x_i$ means that $x_i = c_\alpha u_\alpha +\cdots$. Does this make sense? In addition, I want to say that I don't know whether it is true, and would accept the equality of dimensions instead if it is false. I changed that sentence. Thank you for your correction!

But $u_\alpha$ is a subspace. I think you are meaning to say that the projection of $x$ on the weight space is non-$0$. Now what does it mean for $S_x^\pm$ to be generated by a set of roots? I doubt that it is equivalent to the statement about proper parabolics, though I'm not sure because I haven't understood the statement yet. (For example, whatever root condition you are assuming, do you mean to assume it for all systems of positive roots?)

I need to write $u_\alpha$ as $\langle u_\alpha \rangle$ since this is one-dimensional subspace. So $u_\alpha$ is a generator of this space. I am sorry for this confusion.
Maybe $S_x^{+}$ is not generated by a set of roots. I want to say that $S_x^{+}$ is not contained in any $R^+$, where $R^+$ is generated by at most $sr(G)-1$ linearly independent roots in $\Phi^+$. (Same for $S_x^-$.) If $S_x^+$ (or $S_x^-$) is contained in $R^+$, then I think that we can take a parabolic subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}\oplus \underset{\alpha \in R^+\cup \Phi^-}{\oplus } \langle u_\alpha \rangle$. Am I right?

OK. I think you are making a lot of choices that you don't really want to make. I have written a positive answer to what I think you mean, and explained why some other interpretations don't work.

I think you are asking if, when $\mathfrak g$ is a reductive, complex Lie algebra, a collection of elements not jointly contained in any proper parabolic subgroup of $\mathfrak g$ has central centraliser. (If you impose this requirement only for parabolics containing a fixed torus, then it is not true; the element $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ of $\mathfrak{gl}_2$ is not contained in any proper parabolic containing the diagonal torus, but is non-central. If you ask for real instead of complex, then the same element is not contained in any proper parabolic at all.)
This is true. Suppose $y$ commutes with each $x_i$. There is a parabolic subalgebra $\mathfrak p$ that contains $C_\mathfrak g(y)$, hence all $x_i$s, and whose nilpotent radical contains the nilpotent part of $y$. Since $\mathfrak p$ is not proper, its nilpotent radical is trivial, so $y$ is semisimple. Then the centraliser of $y$ is a Levi subalgebra containing all the $x_i$s, so it is also not proper. That is, $y$ is central.

I appreciate your kind answer and comments! This is very helpful to me.
